# Is anything known about the derivative of the quantum dilogarithm?

Tags: qa.quantum-algebra, q-analogs

Faddeev's noncompact quantum dilogarithm is the function defined by
$$
  \Phi_{\mathsf b}(z) =
  \exp
  \int_{\mathbb{R} + i\varepsilon}
  \frac{
    e^{-2i zw}
  }{
    4 \sinh(w \mathsf b ) \sinh(w/\mathsf b)
  }
  \frac{dw}{w}
$$
for $|\Im z| < |\Im c_{\mathsf b}|$, where $c_{\mathsf b} = \frac{i}{2} \left( \mathsf b + \mathsf b^{-1}\right)$. It can be analytically continued to a meromorphic function on $\mathbb{C}$ with a number of interesting properties. (For example, see [1, Appendix A].) In general, it is a sort of quantum analogue of the (exponentiated) dilogarithm function
$
L(z) = e^{\operatorname{Li}_2(e^z)/2\pi i}
$
where
$
\operatorname{Li}_2(z)
=
-
\int_{0}^{z} \frac{\log(1-t)}{t} dt
$
is the usual dilogarithm.

Has anyone studied the derivative $\Phi_{\mathsf b}'(z)$, or the logarithmic derivative $\Phi_{\mathsf b}'(z)/\Phi_{\mathsf b}(z)$? Presumably it would be an analogue of the logarithmic derivative $- \log(1 - e^z)$ of $L(z)$ (here I'm ignoring some factors of $2\pi i$).

[1] "A TQFT from quantum Teichmueller Theory" [arXiv:1109.6295](https://arxiv.org/abs/1109.6295)

Comment: According to integral formula of Woronowicz https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_dilogarithm
$$
\Phi_{\mathsf b}(z) =\exp\left(\frac{i}{2\pi}\int_{\mathbb{R}}\frac{\ln(1+e^{t b^2+2\pi bz})}{1+e^t}\,dt\right).
$$
Thus logarithmic derivative is
$$
\Phi'_{\mathsf b}(z)/
\Phi_{\mathsf b}(z) =bie^{2\pi bx}\int_{\mathbb{R}}\frac{e^{t b^2}}{(1+e^{t b^2+2\pi bx})(1+e^t)}\,dt.
$$
After substitution $e^t=s$ the integral above becomes
$$
\int_0^\infty\frac{s^{b^2-1}}{(s+1) \left(1+s^{b^2} e^{2 \pi  b x}\right)}\,ds.
$$